# Xdebug requests being ignored sometimes

Tags: php, nginx, phpstorm, xdebug

I am sending requests and can breakpoint through my code with PhpStorm but from time to time a can not reconnect and make another requests, I get a timeout than in my browser.

Than I have to wait 1 min until my nginx connection is deleted automatically and than I can reconnect with xdebug.

Very weird is, that I can not open any connection to the nginx webserver when this happens - not only xdebug session on xdebug port are not possible also serving static files does not work. This effect is limited to my IP, other users get served by the webserver.

It seems like the connection is held open and is not reused. I have tried it with nginx with keep alive connections and without, but no difference.

I am using PHP 7 (v7.0.15-1) FPM with xdebug (v2.5.0) and nginx (1.10.0).

Comment: *(just a thought)* Maybe you have not closed previous debug session in PhpStorm? If so -- see if increasing a number of simultaneous debug sessions in PhpStorm from default 1 will be any better (but better to close previous sessions properly, if that's the reason, of course). Collecting xdebug logs (from xdebug side) may also be useful (it will tell if xdebug is trying to make that additional connection and what not)

Comment: I have tried increasing the number of xdebug connections and it did not help. It does not only affect xdebug calls but also normal webserver calls over port 80 are not possible until the 1 minute is reached.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have any other PHPStorm debug sessions running

Comment: no, I do not have other conenctions runing

Comment: So .. what xdebug log has to say? If nothing (all looks absolutely normal) then it's rather PHP/web server itself and not xdebug/PhpStorm. I'm not a nginx expert by any means (just ordinary user from this particular aspect) but I would look into nginx logs/traces. P.S. When it happens -- can you get any requests served at all? From another IP? Even static files?

Comment: Nice idea: I found out that only my IP is blocked and even a requestr on a static file is blocked

Comment: make certain you have enough FPM workers in your config.